# TYPO3 get frontend user without logging in

Tags: repository, typo3

I have a shop function, where a user can send his basket without being logged in. He only has to register with the sr_feuser_register form and when the form is valid and the user is stored I forward to my basket send function, here I want to read the user with uid from the FrontendUserRepository, but I always get back a null object here. Is it possible, that my controller can not read userdata while the User is not logged in? I also checked while I activated the user dataset manually - same result, null)

Georg

Comment: If no user is logged in, how do you want to identify the user?

Do you forward any information to your function? Like the uid of the created user?

Comment: of course i have the id of the user i want

Comment: do you use the correct functions? I assume you request the data from the current (login) user. did you do a findByUid()?

Comment: Also is the user active or hidden? As the repository might check the enable fields in addition.

Otherwise use Doctrine if you got a recent TYPO3 version.